# noatime is set in OS X but the system continues updating the last access time

Tags: macos, ssd

after replacing my iMac HDD by a new SSD, I activated the noatime option for the partition on the SSD. In fact, when I type

```
mount | grep 'noatime'
```

I get:

```
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled, noatime)
```

as expected. However, I is still able to show the last access data of the files, and this date is updated each time I open a file... Is it normal? I expected that the last access date is never updated...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The last access date is updated every time the file is accessed. The `noatime` option just means that a mere access time update won't trigger a disk write. It will still be updated in memory and it will still be written to disk if something else triggers a disk write.

Comment: Thanks @david-schwartz. In that case, there is no reason to activate the noatime. All in all, the SSD is going to "suffer" all the writes... right?

Comment: Not exactly, the number of writes is gonna be reduced by using noatime flag!

Comment: What geeth said is correct. Setting the `noatime` flag will reduce the number of writes.